How to select record from the database using LINQ statement
The code below work fine in another project, but l am currently working on another using LINQ.
 [Route("plantsummary")]
    [HttpGet]
    public object plantsummary()
    {
        string query = "SELECT Name, CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) AS Item,
          Botanical, STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Store FROM planting 
        WHERE CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) = CONCAT(a.Name, ', ', a.Variety)
        FOR XML PATH (''))  , 1, 1, '')  AS [Store] FROM planting AS a 
        GROUP BY Name, Variety, Botanical";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        SqlDataReader dr;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                dr.Close();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return new JsonResult(dt);
  }

l want to write the above SQL select statement in LINQ (below code).
 public IActionResult UrlDatasource([FromBody] DataManagerRequest dm)
    {
        IEnumerable DataSource = _context.planting.ToList();
        DataOperations operation = new DataOperations();            
        return dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = DataSource }) : Json(DataSource);
    }

planting table



Id
Item
Botanical Name
Location




1
Apple
Malus spp
Block C


2
Coffee
Coffea
Block A


3
Coffee
Coffea
Block B


4
Apple
Malus spp
Block B



Expected output



Id
Item
Location




1
Apple, Malus spp
Block C, Block B


2
Coffee, Coffea
Block A, Block B




The first table is the result returned from your query? I don't see your query contains the Id column.

If you have working sql (and presumably optimized to a certain degree) why not use it? Surrounding it with another layer of abstraction like EF that presumably created less optimized sql does not help to much or makes better more performing results. You can execute raw sql via EF.

First, which SQL Server version are you using? There's no reason to use this XML trick to concatenate strings, you can use STRING_AGG since 2017. Second, LINQ isn't a database query language. Either EF or another ORM will convert it to SQL but there's no way to specify STRING_AGG in LINQ

In SQL you may be able to write SELECT CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) as Item, STRING_AGG(Location) as Location FROM Planting GROUP BY Name,Variety

By saying LINQ, do you mean some kind of ORM? Which one exactly? There are many LINQ-ORMs.

Look at Function Mappings

Your query is almost close to the answer. Some changes from your query:

GROUP BY Name, Variety

The sub-query in Location column should use Botanical instead of Store which I don't see you are providing this column in the planting table.

Add the column ID generated for each row (Optional)


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name, Variety)) AS ID
  , CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) AS Item
  , STUFF( 
      (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Botanical FROM planting 
      WHERE CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) = CONCAT(a.Name, ', ', a.Variety)
      FOR XML PATH (''))  , 1, 1, '')  AS [Location] 
FROM planting AS a 
GROUP BY Name, Variety

Query revised:
As @Panagiotis suggested with SQL 2017 and above you can work with STRING_AGG
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name, Variety) AS ID
  , CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) AS Item
  , STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),  Botanical), ',')  AS [Location] 
FROM planting
GROUP BY Name, Variety

As you are asking for LINQ query
var result = (from p in _context.Plantings
    group p by new { p.Name, p.Variety } into g
    select new
    {
        Item = g.Key.Name + "," + g.Key.Variety
        Location = String.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Botanical).Distinct())
    })
    .ToList();


Demo @ DB Fiddle

All SQL Server versions since 2017 have STRING_AGG. The downvote is because GROUP BY CONCAT(Name, ', ', Variety) will prevent the use of indexes, forcing a full table scan. GROUP BY Name,Variety does the same job without the penalty

Thanks @Panagiotis for your feedback. I amend the answer.  Demo 2 @ SQL Fiddle
